# How can this regular expression be modified to detect and ignore too many characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string which I am trying to parse with a regex:

```
"id=12345,123456,1234567"
```

The string is part of a hash value and can appear in one of the following ways:

```
"#id=12345" // single value
"#id=12345,123456,1234567" // multiple values
"#id=12345,123456,1234567&Another=Value" // one or more values followed by an ampersand.
```

**Only numbers with 5 or 6 characters are valid**, so the result should be an array like below:

```
['12345', '123456']
```

This is the regex I currently have but it also includes the 7-digit number (last one above):

```
"id=12345,123456,1234567".match(/([0-9]{5,6})+/g);
```

Resulting in:

```
["12345", "123456", "123456"] // Should only have two items
```

What can I do to prevent numbers larger then 6 digits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest would be to use word boundaries:

```
/(\b[0-9]{5,6}\b)+/g
```

And I'm not sure why you're using the `+` quantifier here...

```
/\b[0-9]{5,6}\b/g
```

That should be enough.

Word boundaries match in between `\w\W`, `\W\w`, `\w$` and `^\w` by the way.